# Cast an object to child type? (Downcasting)

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, parent-child, downcast

I understand that downcasting may not be the best way to achieve my desires, but it at least indicates the kind of solutions I have running through my head. Any alternative suggestions are welcome.

Alright, so may as well dive into my code:

```
public void triggerItem(Item item) 
{
    if (item is Weapon) {
        equipWeapon(item);
    }       
}

public void equipWeapon(Weapon weapon) 
{

}
```

So I basically have an inventory set up, and of course the inventory will contain various types of items (weapons, armour, consumables, etc.) As you can see I have an Item class and then a Weapon class and a bunch of others which all inherit Item.

Now, I intend to call this function when the player clicks on an item in their inventory, then call different functions depending on the particular Type of Item.

But because `equipWeapon()` receives Weapon, it doesn't like it when I just pass it an Item.

I understand that I could change my code to `equipWeapon(Item item)`, but the ultimate destination of the object requires a Weapon type and I'm reluctant to change that. It seems like a dirty solution and a step in the wrong direction, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This should be a big reg flag in your design.  You need to code to interfaces  and generalize

Comment: move *equip* method to *Item* class as an abstract method

Comment: Ah I expected to feel silly when the solutions started rolling in. I actually deleted the equip() method from my Item class earlier today when I got carried away restructuring. Bit of a brainfart moment I suppose. 

Many thanks to all of the people who have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your base class a method that causes it to be equipped, and implement it in the type-specific class that knows how to equip itself.

Example:

```
abstract class Item
{
    public abstract void Equip();
}

class Weapon
{
    public override void Equip()
    {
        equipWeapon(this);
    }
}
```

Then triggerItem becomes trivial:

```
public void triggerItem(Item item) 
{
    item.Equip();
}
```

If you need to call equipWeapon on a different class (e.g. whatever class contains `triggerItem`) you can make the class part of the interface:

```
abstract class Item
{
    public abstract void Equip(Game context);
}

class Weapon
{
    public override void Equip(Game context)
    {
        context.equipWeapon(this);
    }
}

class Game
{
    public void triggerItem(Item item) 
    {
        item.Equip(this);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This solves it.

```
public void triggerItem(Item item) 
{
    if (item is Weapon) {
        equipWeapon((Weapon)item);
    }       
}

public void equipWeapon(Weapon weapon) 
{

}
```

What you do here is downcasting the `Item` to `Weapon` while passing to `equipWeapon(Weapon weapon)`.

Comment: I answered his question precisely, what is it that you dont like about my answer? Am I missing something?